# Type equality function

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to define a function like so:

```
f :: (C a, C b) => a -> Maybe b
```

Such that:

```
f = Just
```

when type `a` = `b`, and

```
f _ = Nothing
```

when type `a` /= `b`?

Note that:

- I don't want to use overlapping instances.
- I'd prefer not to have a class constraint `C`, but I'm pretty sure it's necessary (particularly if I want to avoid overlapping instances).
- I want to define only a single instance for each type I want to compare in this scheme, defining a class `Equal a b` makes this problem trivial but it then requires `n^2` instances which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Just this

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast

```
cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
```

### Example of use

Function cast can be a part of "type casting system like object-oriented languages". Bacteria and Fungus are Life. They can be upcasted to Life. And Life may be able to downcast to Bacteria or Fungus.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

data SomeLife = forall l . Life l => SomeLife l
        deriving Typeable

instance Show SomeLife where
        show (SomeLife l) = "SomeLife " ++ show l

class (Typeable l, Show l) => Life l where
        toLife :: l -> SomeLife
        fromLife :: SomeLife -> Maybe l

        toLife = SomeLife
        fromLife (SomeLife l) = cast l

instance Life SomeLife where
        toLife = id
        fromLife = Just

data Bacteria = Bacteria deriving (Typeable, Show)

instance Life Bacteria

data Fungus = Fungus deriving (Typeable, Show)

instance Life Fungus

castLife :: (Life l1, Life l2) => l1 -> Maybe l2
castLife = fromLife . toLife

filterLife :: (Life l1, Life l2) => [l1] -> [l2]
filterLife = catMaybes . map castLife

withLifeIO :: (Life l1, Life l2) => l1 -> (l2 -> IO ()) -> IO ()
withLifeIO l f = maybe (return ()) f $ castLife l

withYourFavoriteLife :: Life l => (l -> IO ()) -> IO ()
withYourFavoriteLife act = do
        withLifeIO Bacteria act
        withLifeIO Fungus act

main :: IO ()
main = do
        let     sls :: Life l => [l]
                sls = filterLife [
                        SomeLife Bacteria,
                        SomeLife Fungus,
                        SomeLife Fungus ]
        print (sls :: [SomeLife])
        print (sls :: [Bacteria])
        print (sls :: [Fungus])
        withYourFavoriteLife (print :: SomeLife -> IO ())
        withYourFavoriteLife (print :: Bacteria -> IO ())
        withYourFavoriteLife (print :: Fungus -> IO ())
```

This technic extend to type hierarchy system. Whole Life module is here.
https://github.com/YoshikuniJujo/test_haskell/blob/master/features/existential_quantifications/type_hierarchy/Life.hs

Exception system use this technic. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I'm after. Cheers.

Comment: can you explain this with an example, I would like to understand properly. thanks :)

Comment: I added example of use. Is this what you want? Or do you want to know the inside of function cast?